# Sending a parameter in filename with quotes in loadrunner

Tags: escaping, parameter-passing, filenames, loadrunner

How to pass a parameter in a file name with quotes in loadrunner?

I tried to forcefully parameterise by right clicking on a word in the filename and assigned that to VUser id. But it didn't work as I got a Warning: Invalid parameter detected in function.

In the below example, stoid is a variable that I extract from the screen and `savetofileint` is a C function I wrote to create a file with the name mentioned in quotes.

`savingToFileInt(stoid,"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\{NewParam_1}.txt");`

Another function has to retrieve the stoid from the file later. That's the reason I need to send VUser id or iteration number in the filename to identify it. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `lr_eval_string` to the parameter substitution.

```
// savingToFileInt(stoid,"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\{NewParam_1}.txt");

lr_save_string("123456","NewParam_1");
lr_message("[%s]", lr_eval_string("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\{NewParam_1}.txt"));

// savingToFileInt(stoid,lr_eval_string("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\{NewParam_1}.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> That's the reason I need to send VUser id or iteration number in the filename to identify it.

Have you considered the advantage of lr_output_message() which will send your message to the controller during a test?  Or, have you considered that the standard log model will write individual messages.

Something to keep in mind, by involving the local filesystem in your performance test you are introducing a bottleneck on the local load generator.   You will now have tens, hundreds, perhaps thousands of individual threads fighting for access to the write head for your drive.

I would recommend another model for attempting to do what you are doing, which is to save a value to a file for use later.  Consider seriously the use of Virtual Table Server, an independent queuing solution such as RabbitMQ or even any of the queue services at cloud providers as an arbitration mechanism to pass data back and forth between virtual users.   Using the local file system for this type of passing is going to be problematic under load.  It is much better to use a service independent of the local load generators for this type of intra-virtual user passing of data. This recommendation holds across all performance testing tools, commercial and open source.

Comment: Thank you so much for redirecting me this way. I would have upvoted this had you given some instructions and coding needed for this in VTS. But I found the set up steps, coding etc in the internet and worked on it. It is super cool and so less coding.

Comment: My style is to point you to the start of a path and allow you to do the research and first implementations.   As most of us in IT are hands on learners (as opposed to visual or audio learners), I find that this is the best method for performance engineers